# Using MonoTouch How do i save a PDF file from a url directly to iBooks?

Tags: pdf, uiwebview, xamarin.ios, ibooks, xamarin

At the moment I pass the PDF URL to the UIWebView and display it in the app. The PDF files are external and not included within the bundle.

I want to provide the user with the option to save the file to iBooks once it is displayed in the UIWebView.

I don't want to save the PDF file in the app itself I would like to view it in the UIWebView and add a button on the Nav bar; "Save to iBooks".

1  - So how do i detect if iBooks is installed?

2  - How do i save the PDF file into iBooks from the Nav bar?

I have found some references to saving the file locally in the app itself but I want to save it directly to iBooks.

I am not using XCode but Monotouch/Monodevelop.

Thanks - its a little confusing for a newbie to monotouch.

Answer (score 1):

I've asked [almost exactly the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375472/add-open-in-ibooks-to-uiwebview) recently.

It's not for MonoTouch but will probably give you the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'm still having some difficulty translating the XCode code to Monotouch C#. I was hoping there might be an example out there somewhere!