# Use UIActivityViewController to share all types of files

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, file-sharing

I want to use `UIActivityViewController` to share files from my iOS app. The main question for me is how do I handle different file types.

What I'v got so far:

**Images**

```
public void OpenInExternalApp(string filepath)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filepath))
        return;

    UIImage uiImage = UIImage.FromFile(filepath);

    // Define the content to share
    var activityItems = new NSObject[] { uiImage };
    UIActivity[] applicationActivities = null;

    var activityController = new UIActivityViewController(activityItems, applicationActivities);

    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone)
    {
        // Phone
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(activityController, true, null);
    }
    else
    {
        // Tablet
        var popup = new UIPopoverController(activityController);
        UIView view = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View;
        CGRect rect = new CGRect(view.Frame.Width/2, view.Frame.Height, 50, 50);
        popup.PresentFromRect(rect, view, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, true);
    }
}
```

Don't know if from the memory management aspect it is a good idea to load the image at once. What will happen if the image is too big for holding it completely in RAM? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19551378/426227) for example.

**Strings**

```
var activityItems = new NSObject[] { UIActivity.FromObject(new NSString(text)) };
```

Only text.

**NSUrl**

```
NSUrl url = NSUrl.CreateFileUrl(filepath, false, null);
```

Here in most cases the same app appear. But for example the PDF reader doesn't appear for a PDF file. The preview in mail on the other side shows Adobe Acrobat.

**Everything**

```
var activityItems = new NSObject[] { NSData.FromFile(filepath) };
```

The last approach has the disadvantage that not all apps are displayed, which for example could open a PDF file. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19551378/426227) applies.

I want to use all types of files. I don't think a subclass of `UIActivity` would help here. Perhaps a sublcass of `UIActivityItemProvider`?

<sub>Side note: You can also post your solutions in Objective C/Swift.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to implement `UIActivityItemProvider`, but here again not all apps where shown for the corresponding filetype. E.g. for a docx-document Word was not shown.

Now I switched to `UIDocumentInteractionController` and now there are many apps available.

```
UIDocumentInteractionController documentController = new UIDocumentInteractionController();
documentController.Url = new NSUrl(filepath, false);
string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filepath).Substring(1);
string uti = UTType.CreatePreferredIdentifier(UTType.TagClassFilenameExtension.ToString(), fileExtension, null);
documentController.Uti = uti;

UIView presentingView = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View;
documentController.PresentOpenInMenu(CGRect.Empty, presentingView, true);
```

Imho there are too many apps, because the file type xml should not be really be supported by a PDF reader, but it is. Nevertheless, it seems to work now thanks to [this post](https://diego.org/2014/11/26/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-vs-uiactivityviewcontroller/):

> In general if you’re sharing an image or url, you might want to use a UIActivityViewController. If you’re sharing a document, you might want to use a UIDocumentInteractionController.

Comment: your `UIView presentingView = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View` helped me